# Making org to beamer example work

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf, beamer

Tried running the example in [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/A-Beamer-example.html#A-Beamer-example):

```
#+TITLE: Example Presentation
#+AUTHOR: Carsten Dominik
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:t num:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+BEAMER_THEME: Madrid
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col)

* This is the first structural section

** Frame 1
*** Thanks to Eric Fraga                                           :B_block:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_COL: 0.48
    :BEAMER_ENV: block
    :END:
    for the first viable Beamer setup in Org
*** Thanks to everyone else                                        :B_block:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_COL: 0.48
    :BEAMER_ACT: <2->
    :BEAMER_ENV: block
    :END:
    for contributing to the discussion
**** This will be formatted as a beamer note                       :B_note:
     :PROPERTIES:
     :BEAMER_env: note
     :END:
** Frame 2 (where we will not use columns)
*** Request
    Please test this stuff!
```

But this results in (when doing a `C-c C-e l p`) an output pdf where all the contents are just dumped together into a single slide.

How can I have distinct slides (where heading level 2 leads to next frame and heading level 1 leads to next section. That's what `H:2` does, right?).

Tried the one [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/tutorial.html) too but that too wouldn't work.

I haven't set a value for `org-latex-classes`.

- Org version: 9.4.4
- Emacs version: 27.2

Any idea how this can be made to work properly?

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate question: Beamer export to PDF is done with `C-c C-e l P` (note the capital P).

Comment: Yes. Thanks! That and adding `(require 'ox-beamer)` made it work.